# User input to a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to take in user input and add it to a list but I have not been able to get it working. I'm still new to scheme and have been browsing around to try to figure it out but I haven't had any luck.

```
(display "Continue to enter numbers until satisfied then enter e to end")
(newline)
(define (intlist number)
  (define number(read-line))
  (cond (number? number)
        (cons lst (number))
        (else
         (display lst)
         done')))
```

this is what I have so far. Any help or direction to where I can learn a bit more is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct, but it doesn't work, because:

- Variable `lst` doesn't exist and with this expression `(number)`, you are calling some undefined function `number`.
- `done'` is badly written `'done`.
- Function [`cons`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._cons%29%29) expects element as first argument and other element or list as second argument.
  See these examples:

```
> (cons 1 2)
'(1 . 2)
> (cons 1 '())
'(1)
> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
'(1 2 3)
```

Last example is important here- your function will be recursive and it will return a cons cell in each step. If I will follow your solution, this can be enough:

```
(define (list-from-user)
  (let ((number (read)))
    (if (number? number)
        (cons number (list-from-user))
        '())))
```

(Note that I used [`read`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._read%29%29) instead of `read-line`, because `read-line` returns string, and [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) instead of `define`.)

If you really want to wait for `e`, you must decide, what happens if user enters something that isn't number and isn't `e`- maybe just ignore it?

```
(define (list-from-user)
  (let ((user-input (read)))
    (cond ((number? user-input) (cons user-input (list-from-user)))
          ((eq? user-input 'e) '())
          (else (list-from-user)))))
```

Then just add some wrapping function with output:

```
(define (my-fn)
  (begin (display "Continue to enter numbers until satisfied then enter e to end")
         (newline)
         (list-from-user)))
```

and call it

```
> (my-fn)
```

Note that my function returns list with numbers, instead of some useless `'done`, so I can use that function in other functions.

```
(define (sum-of-list)
  (let ((lst (my-fn)))
    (format "Sum of given list is ~a." (apply + lst))))

> (sum-of-list)
```